# LINQ to SQL with null values

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Can anyone help me figure this out?

The below code works fine and gets inside the if statument

```
foreach (var m in msg)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.PhoneNumber))
    {
        m.PhoneNumber = (from c in db.Customers
                            where c.CustomerID == m.CustomerID
                            select c.PhoneNumber).Single();
    }
}
```

However in the below code phoneNumber is never set

```
foreach (var m in msg.Where(z => (z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "")))
{
     m.PhoneNumber = (from c in db.Customers
                      where c.CustomerID == m.CustomerID
                      select c.PhoneNumber).Single();
}
```

I'm presuming its because the top code actually evaluates the expression whereas the below dosent. If that is the case then how can you check for null on an unevaluated LINQ query?

**EDIT** Just to stop confusion here is how msg is poplated in both cases

```
    var msg = from m in db.Messages
              where (m.StatusID == (int)MessageStatus.Submitted && m.MessageBoxTypeID == (int)MessageBoxType.Outbox)
              select m;
```

Comment: Are you using the same code in both cases for creating the `msg` sequence? (The two snippets seem equivalent to me, unless I’m missing something.)

Comment: Could you show us the code for `msg`?

Comment: I suggest setting the Log on your DataContext to `Console.Out` (or a file) and seeing what the actual queries being generated are.  Run those same queries by hand to see what you get.  The code looks like it ought to work the same, but obviously something else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m somewhat baffled by this one, but I have a wild guess. If the `msg` sequence is an `IQueryable<T>` which translates to an SQL query, then the behavior of the two snippets may vary. Suppose you have:

```
var msg = 
    from m in dataContext.MyTable
    select m;
```

Your first snippet would cause the entire `msg` sequence to be enumerated, thereby issuing an unfiltered `SELECT…FROM` command to the database and fetching all the rows within your table.

```
foreach (var m in msg)
```

On the other hand, your second snippet applies a filter to your sequence *before* it is enumerated. Thus, the command issued to the database is a `SELECT…FROM…WHERE`.

```
foreach (var m in msg.Where(z => (z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "")))
```

There are various cases where the behavior of a filter applied in .NET would differ from its translation to Transact-SQL. For one, case-sensitivity. In your case, I assume that the mismatch is caused by entries whose `PhoneNumber` consists of whitespace, as these may match the empty string in SQL Server.

To test this possibility, check what happens if you change your second snippet to:

```
foreach (var m in msg.ToList().Where(z => (z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "")))
```

**Edit**: Your issue might be that your query is being executed again during subsequent access (when you check whether `PhoneNumber` was set).

If you execute:

```
foreach (var m in msg.Where(z => (z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "")))
{
    m.PhoneNumber = …
}

bool stillHasNulls = msg.Any(z => z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "");
```

You will find that `stillHasNulls` might still evaluate to `true`, since your assignment to `m.PhoneNumber` is being lost when you re-evaluate the `msg` sequence (in the above case, when you execute `msg.Any`, which issues an `EXISTS` command to the database).

For your `m.PhoneNumber` assignments to be preserved, you need to either persist them to the database (if that’s what you want), or else make sure that you’re accessing the same sequence elements each time. One way to do this would be to pre-populate the sequence as a collection, using `ToList`.

```
msg = msg.Where(z => (z.PhoneNumber == null || z.PhoneNumber == "")).ToList();
foreach (var m in msg)
{
    m.PhoneNumber = …
}
```

In the above code, the filter still gets issued to the database as a `SELECT…FROM…WHERE`, but the result is evaluated eagerly, and then stored as a list within `msg`. Any subsequent queries on `msg` would be evaluated against the pre-populated in-memory collection (which would contain any new values you assign to its elements).

Comment: The ToList() would evaluate the statment and would work (be the same as the second snippit. I more wanted to know how to check if null without evaluating the expression.

Comment: How are you checking whether `PhoneNumber` is set? Are you setting a breakpoint on your assignment statement, or are you checking the values of the elements of `msg` _after_ the loop?

Comment: If you just want to check for `null` as part of the query (without eager evaluation), then your second snippet is correct.